# TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined in react-native-app-auth

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

Im trying to inclue react-native-app-auth in my react native app, but whenever i use the methods(say authorize or revoke) i get the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rkVj.png)

here is my code

`import { authorize  } from 'react-native-app-auth';
  accessTokenRequest = async () => {
    const config = {
        issuer: 'http://localhost:8080',
        clientId: 'am.identity.bpss.com',
        redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth-redirect',
        scopes: ['read','write'],
        usePKCE: true,
        serviceConfiguration: {
            authorizationEndpoint: "http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize",
            tokenEndpoint: "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token",
            revocationEndpoint: ""
        },
    };
    // use the client to make the auth request and receive the authState
    try {
        const result = await authorize(config);
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}`

il call this function when login button is clicked.

here is my package.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ofce.png)

Comment: share the code what you have done

Comment: its been added.

Comment: Have you solved this, Please share your solution @arjunpathy